# encoding error : input conversion failed due to input error when using tfhpple

Tags: ios, parsing, xpath, html-parsing, tfhpple

```
NSData *htmlData=[html dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
TFHpple *htmlParser=[TFHpple hppleWithHTMLData:htmlData];

NSString *threadListXpathQuertString=@"//div[@id='postlist']/div";
NSLog(@"%@",threadListXpathQuertString);
NSArray *threadList=[htmlParser searchWithXPathQuery:threadListXpathQuertString];
```

html is a nsstring, when it runs at the last line code ,it occures error.

> encoding error : input conversion failed due to input error, bytes 0x20 0x2D 0x20 0x44
>
> encoding error : input conversion failed due to input error, bytes 0x20 0x2E 0x2E 0x2E
>
> encoding error : input conversion failed due to input error, bytes 0x3C 0x2F 0x61 0x3E
>
> encoding error : input conversion failed due to input error, bytes 0x3C 0x2F 0x61 0x3E
>
> I/O error : encoder error
> Nodes was nil.

Comment: i soled it. convert the gbk charset to utf-8 charset can solve this.html=[html stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"gbk" withString:@"utf-8"];

Comment: Then perhaps you should add this as an answer instead of a comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i solved it. convert the gbk charset to utf-8 charset can solve this.

```
html=[html stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"gbk" withString:@"utf-8"];
```